# Use props outside of render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to access my prop "post" from my parent. I can access it inside render(), but not above where I have my getCom(). How can I make the prop available in functions and not only in the render? I tried to use `this.item.id.bind(this)`, but that does not work.

Parent:

```
<LoadComments post={item.id}/>
```

Child

```
class LoadComments extends Component {
  getCom = async () => {

    // Thid does not work

    this.unsubscribe = await firestore.collection("comments").where("post", "==", this.props.post).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
     // Rest of code

  }
  render() {
    return (

      // This works:

      {this.props.post}

    )
  }
```

Comment: Are you super(ing) props?

Comment: Are you passing an `id` prop?

Comment: Am I missing something? You don't have a prop named `id`. You have a prop named `post`. `this.props.id` or `this.props.item.id` is `undefined`. You have `this.props.post` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you see you pass `id` as `post` to your child component :

```
<LoadComments post={item.id}/>
```

so you must use this :

```
this.props.post
```

if you want to use id you must pas it as `id` like this :

```
<LoadComments id={item.id}/>
```

Answer (score 4):

To use the value of

```
 item.id
```

in your child component what you should do is:

In Parent:

```
<LoadComments post={item.id}>
```

In Child Component:

```
class LoadComments extends Component {

   async getCom(props) => {

   // This would work now

  this.unsubscribe = await firestore.collection("comments").where("post", "==", 
  props.post).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
   // Rest of code

   }
  render() {
    const props = this.props;
      return (

        {this.props.post}

        getCom(props)

 )
}
```

You have to store the props in a static component in render method and then pass the props to the function declared outside the render method.